# GooglePlusAPI return error 'Legacy People API has not been used in project'

Tags: oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm trying google auth2 with passport.But, an error hapenned.

GooglePlusAPIError: Legacy People API has not been used in project 556727539509 before or it is disabled. Enable it by [visiting](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=556727539509)  then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at C:\Users\rosic\Documents\desafio\oauth-playlist-lesson-9\node_modules\passport-google-oauth20\lib\strategy.js:95:21
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\rosic\Documents\desafio\oauth-playlist-lesson-9\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\rosic\Documents\desafio\oauth-playlist-lesson-9\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys = require('./keys');

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        // options for google strategy
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect'
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // passport callback function
        console.log('passport callback ');
        console.log(profile);
    })
);
```

Comment: Same story here... Still looking for solution...

Comment: I was just studying, then I change the GoogleStrategy to GithubStrategy and my code work perfectly. The configuration in GitHub site is more easy

Comment: @RosicleiaFrasson, Please add a link to the solution that worked for you. Or share more light on the matter.

Comment: @amaugosomto don't work with google strategy. I was only testing, then I tried with github strategy and work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install/upgrade to the latest version of passport, passport-google-oauth20